# Are questions of the type "which countries this legislation happens" on topic in Law SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to know in which countries certain legislation happens. Some SE might consider questions asking for a list of things to be "too broad" or off-topic, but in this case the set of options is limited to around 200. Are these kind of questions on topic in Law SE?

Comment: How do you get 200? 196 countries + 50 states in the US (plus military and maritime law) + 7 States in Australia (plus military and maritime law) + 3 countries in the UK (plus ...) + 29 states in India + 12 provinces in Canada + 34 provinces in China + 32 states in Mexico + ... I would guess you would be looking at closer to 1,000+ when you go through them all

Answer (score 4):

Some "list" questions are allowed as community wikis.  (They have to be community wiki to avoid proliferation of partial answers.)  But this is a very difficult type of question for several reasons:

1. There are far more legislative jurisdictions than there are countries.  For example, just in the U.S. there are many subjects of legislation that are left to states, and even smaller jurisdictions (counties, townships, associations...).
2. Depending on the law in question, the answer could be subject to frequent change.  E.g., there are communities and websites dedicated to trying to keep track of what the current laws are on one specific subject like [audio recording](https://www.rcfp.org/reporters-recording-guide/state-state-guide) or [concealed carrying firearms](https://www.usacarry.com/concealed_carry_permit_information.html), and that's just in the 50 United States!
3. This has been tried before: When you read about law on Wikipedia you will often find attempts to list countries that have implemented a specific legal measure, and the variations in how they have done so.  I don't think I have ever seen a list or page that claims to be exhaustive.  Most often a legal principle will be described and then the current law in just a few major countries will be detailed.